Tkinter event loop can't process some key combinations when use <KeyPress> event
Here is the code from another question, which demonstrates the problem very well (I just found it when I was looking for solution for my problem).
So, when you press some specific key combination, the last (3rd key in my future examples) key doesn't generate a signal when pressed.
Here is the code:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()

Label(root, textvariable=var).pack()

history = []


def keyup(e):
    print(e.keycode)
    if e.keycode in history:
        history.pop(history.index(e.keycode))

        var.set(str(history))


def keydown(e):
    if e.keycode not in history:
        history.append(e.keycode)
        var.set(str(history))


frame = Frame(root, width=200, height=200)
frame.bind("<KeyPress>", keydown)
frame.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()

And here is weird key combinations, which doesn't work normally:

d + space + return
e + space + return
shift + e + space
And so go on. First two keys generates an event, but last key, looke like, doesn't even generate the event.

I've spent the whole day to find the solution, but this behaviour doesn't make any sense, bc other combinations works well (w + space + return, as example).
And tkinter can handle more than 3 keypresses. Just test different combinations and you will see, that there is a couple of combinations that simply impossible to press.
What the reason of such behaviour and how can I fix it?
UPD: Several tests with Python 3.10 and 3.12 on Windows 11 and Python 3.11 on Ubuntu 23.10 showed the same behaviour for me (some sequences don't process).

Can confirm Windows11, python 3.11 - please link the mentioned question, since it is related

I can't reproduce it on Linux (Arch - Gnome Wayland, Python 3.12, tcl-8.6.14, tk-8.6). The three keys are detected without problems in all allegedly problematic combinations.

Win11, Python3.12.2 Detects all keys too. Can you try 3.12 and see if it works?

Interestingly it hasn't to be a weird combination like <Space> + <Return>. Pressing <e> + <r> +<t>  also schows just the first 2 pressed keys in the list.

If it's a windows thing, I wonder if the last bit of this paragraph has something to do with it. Quote If you intercept the WM_SYSKEYDOWN message, call DefWindowProc afterward. Otherwise, you will block the operating system from handling the command.

@Thingamabobs, in my case  +  + works well on windows. In addition I've tested this script on Ubuntu 23.10 (not virtual machine, original ubuntu) with python 3.11.6 on separate laptop and achieved the same behaviour as on windows. So, this is not a system/python ver/hardware problem. Looks like it's Tkinter...

Then it might be keyboard dependent and how the keyboard signals those events. I don't see how this is solvable for us.

@Thingamabobs, thats a pity, but it's better to know about "feature" than live without knowledge at all  :)) (+ I've added a link to the question with original code)

@jupiterbjy, I've tested Ubuntu 23.10 with Python 3.11.6 and had the same behaviour as on Windows. Interesting behaviour.

@Mika Python 3.12 Not 3.11, just to make sure if it's because of 3.11's issue or not (if exists). FJSevilla and I both got correct result on both platform with 3.12 after all, and you got errornous results on both platform with 3.11!

@jupiterbjy, I've finished testing now. Python 3.12.2 doesn't work either. And sorry for misunderstandings. I forgot to add python version in the question body (my first failed attempt was with Python 3.10). So, in conclusion, Python 3.10, 3.11, 3.12 didn't work for me

now that makes things real misterious.. almost as if there's some other programs that are listening to those combinations or if that keyboard doesn't allow that very specific keys.. All I can think of now to eliminate possibilities are trying other keyboards or fresh reinstallation of os but that's too much burden honestly. Does AutoHotkey also fail to get that key combo? At least that would confirm us that it's not keyboard / os issue.
